# Is it safe to download and open files?

Tags: 14.04, security, malware

I understand that a virus and malware can exists in Linux.  However, I have read a lot about how Linux is not vulnerable to viruses because of a variety of reasons.  So does that mean that I can download any file (video, audio, or text) from the net, and open in with peace of mind?

For example, what if I were to download an mp3 file from a shady source off the internet.  Then I open and play it with VLC player or Rythmbox.  Am I 100% safe from malware?

Answer (score 1):

### Am 100% safe from malware?

If the question is "Am I 100% safe from malware?" Then the question would be marked as "too broad" and flagged for deletion.

### Are MP3 files safe?

If the question is "Can I safely open a MP3 file downloaded from a shady source with VLC or Rhythombox". Then the answer is:

Yes, **if** you have the installed the latest updates.

MP3-Files are sound files that doesn't contain any part that will be able to direct the computer anything else to do than play their containing sound. So this is safe as long as you are running your software with the latest bug-fixes.

If you **don't** have the latest bug-fixes you might have a bug in your software that could be exploited by someone knowing about this who might try to bring your VLC or Rhythmbox to run arbitrary code on your computer.

I can't remember that this has happened anytime with MP3 files on Linux, but theoretically it still **could** happen. So to be on the safe-side: allways be sure to install the latest bug-fixes.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually almost as many Linux viruses as Windows ones. The reasons why Linux is possibly less prone to viruses are:

```
1. Programs are run as normal user, not Root User
2. More eyeballs on the code, nowhere for malware to hide
3. Vast diversity makes it difficult to reproduce flaws in a system
4. All software and drivers are frequently updated by Package Managers
5. Software is generally installed from vast Repositories not from unfamiliar websites 
6. Developers/programmers are recognized as Rock Gods rather than treated with contempt
7. Elegant, secure code is admired & aspired to. Hasty kludges are an embarrassment
```

Although this does not mean however that viruses cannot run on Linux, or that it is fully virus free. There are many Java viruses out there for instance which don't mind which platform you are on as long as it has a compatible JRE on it.

There is some interesting information on this subject here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Linuxvirus (numbered list quoted from here)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus